# Change _type of a document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have two TYPES in my elasticsearch index. Both have same mapping. I am using one for active documents, while the other for archived ones.

Now, i want to archive a document i.e. change its _type from active to archived. Both are in same index, so i cannot reindex them as well.

Is there a way to do this in Elasticsearch 5.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the type is tricky. You would have to remove and then index the document with the new type.

Why not have a field in your document indicating "activeness". Then you can use a bool query to filter by what you want:

```
  {"query": {
       "bool": {
         "filter": [{"term": {"status", "active"}}],
         "query": { /* your query object here */ }
        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with having a field which indicates the activeness of the document.

(Or)

- Use two different indices for "active" and "inactive" types.
- Use aliases which map to these indices.
- Aliases will give you flexibility to change your indices without downtimes.